# How to get LogCat from Genymotion device

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, genymotion

I'm using Android Studio and I installed the plugin Genymotion as well as program.

Right now I want to debug some application with problem, but if I use Genymotion device there is no LogCat in Android Studio. Is there a way how to add him for this device too?

If not I searched some information from Genymotion FAQ, there is path when you can find LogCat in some directory but when I opened it there was no useful info for me only weird lines I don't understand. I only need a report of why my app crashed.

Here is an example:

```
08-10 18:05:30.445 D/Genyd   (   58): Connected to genybaseband
08-10 18:05:30.445 I/Genyd   (   58): Genyd running
08-10 18:05:30.473 D/DHCP    (   75): ===== DHCP message:
08-10 18:05:30.473 D/DHCP    (   75): op = BOOTREQUEST (1), htype = 1, hlen = 6, hops = 0
08-10 18:05:30.473 D/DHCP    (   75): xid = 0x8e0d0000 secs = 0, flags = 0x8000 optlen = 14
08-10 18:05:30.473 D/DHCP    (   75): ciaddr = 0.0.0.0
08-10 18:05:30.473 D/DHCP    (   75): yiaddr = 0.0.0.0
08-10 18:05:30.473 D/DHCP    (   75): siaddr = 0.0.0.0
08-10 18:05:30.473 D/DHCP    (   75): giaddr = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Did you try `adb logcat` via terminal/command line?

Comment: If you are on a Mac you could try LogRabbit http://lograbbit.com

Comment: I´m using Windows. And no i didnt. I dont know how can i do that?

Comment: Open command line. If you properly have adb installed - enter `adb logcat`. This is all AndroidStudio is showing you.

Comment: [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238) is a few more things you can do with it, like filter and sending to txt file

Answer (score 5):

As a couple of guys correctly pointed, the "adb" works fine.
I use eclipse on Windows, no plugin of Genymotion, but once Genymotion started I run in the shell this command:
c:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe logcat -v threadtime > c:\tmp\logcat_20160609_geny.txt